# Openvswitch CLI versus network files

Tags: openvswitch

There is something I don't get with openvswitch.
Let's say that I want to create br0 and a port on eth0.
As far as I understand, we can setup a bridge and a port through the network configuration files.
But then when should we use openvswitch command line like:

```
ovs-vsctl add-br br0
ovs-vsctl add-port br0 eth0
```

Comment: When testing / scripting ? What's the problem with that ? That's the same thing than using `ip`/`brctl` commands vs using network files. In both case it depends if you want to persist the configuration or not ...

Comment: So you mean that commands don't persist changes?

Answer (score 0):

the network configuration files have nothing to do with OpenVSwitch (OVS).

If you create a bridge trough the network configuration files, it will not be an OVS bridge and you cannot manage it trough OVS nor use OVS advanced features.

OVS store the configuration you made trough ovs-vsctl commands in its own database.